# Unable to upload to FTP using batch script

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have problems to upload files to an ftp using command mput*. When I run the batch file it shows no file found. The filename have spaces.

```
@echo off

for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%F in ('
    wmic PATH Win32_LocalTime GET Day^,Month^,Year /FORMAT:TABLE
') do (
    for /F "tokens=1-3" %%L in ("%%F") do (
        set CurrDay=0%%L
        set CurrMonth=0%%M
        set CurrYear=%%N
    )
)
set CurrDay=%CurrDay:~-2%

set CurrMonth=%CurrMonth:~-2%
echo Current day  :  %CurrDay%
echo Current month:  %CurrMonth%
echo Current year :%CurrYear%

set LOG=%CurrYear%%CurrMonth%.log
set FTPFolder=D:\FTP

echo %FTPFolder%
cd /D %FTPFolder%

ECHO.
@ECHO OFF
ftp -s:TryFTP.txt  
ECHO.
ECHO ***** FTP transfer complete successfully! *****

pause
```

The TryFTP.txt

```
open Servername
user
password
lcd D:\FTP 
cd /HTML
binary
mput *
bye
```

Error I get:

```
binary 
invalid command
mput*
file not found
bye
invalid command
```

but if I try it manually using the same command it works. Can you guys please advise what wrong with it?

Comment: You sure it is connecting? Change your code to this: `ftp -s:TryFTP.txt >ftplog.txt`. Edit your question and post the contents of the log file.

Comment: Also you could shorten up your script a lot by getting the date and time in a format that is easy to parse with substrings. This will give you the data and time in one variable and output as YYYYMMDDhhmmss. `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"`

Comment: yes, it successfully connected to the server.

Comment: I do data automation for a living. I have hundreds of automated tasks that do this every day.  If do not show me the log file of the output of that script file, I really can't help you.

Comment: Also as an additional test, do `!dir` before the `mput`. And show us the real output (as shown by Squashman), not a manual transcript.  As your transcript is not accurate (there's `mput*`, not `mput *`).